# How do I save custom fields from form using _$POST

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have wrote some PHP and HTML that creates a form and then creates a new product upon submission using _$POST. The product creation works; however, ACF doesn't update the fields for some reason.

Here is my code

```
// When user submits product
   if ( isset( $_POST['submit_watch'] ) ) {
      if ( ! empty( $_POST['watch-brand'] ) ) {
         $brand        = $_POST['watch-brand'];
         $model        = $_POST['model'];
         $product_name = $brand.' '.$model;
         $description = $_POST['watch-description'];
         $my_post = array(
         'post_content'   =>  $description, 
         'post_name'      =>  $product_name, 
         'post_title'     =>  $product_name, 
         'post_status'    => 'draft', 
         'post_type'      => 'product', 
         'post_author'    => 1, 
         );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
        $field_key = "field_123456";
        $value = "some new string";
       
        update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
    
        } else {
           echo 'Your Product Title is Missing';
   } 
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that you have the correct field key, and that it accepts the supplied type? What does `update_field` return?

Comment: @ChrisHaas when I goto the post it literally doesn't update anything.

Comment: Are you able to answer the three questions from my previous comment?

Comment: @chrisHaas yes I have the correct field key within the actual application; however, it is in a field group. Does that make a difference? It is also a text field so it should accept those variables according to the ACF documentation, as far as your last question what do you mean what does it return? It isn't doing anything :(

Comment: The group nature is **very** important to this question. Take a look at [`update_sub_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_sub_field/) instead

Answer (score 0):

For those of you wondering how to update a sub field within a group either during `wp_insert_post($post_id)` here is how to do it.

```php
// Group your data into an array:
$values = array(
    'field_name'    =>  $field_one,
    'field_name2'   =>  $field_two,
    'field_name3'   =>  $field_three,
    'field_name4'   =>  $field_four
);

// Update the field using this array as value:
update_field('fieldkey', $values, $post_ID);
```

I ended up figuring this out after a ton of testing and I hope it helps anyone struggling with this in the future.